# CakePHP 3 custom template not working for the button element

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have tried to surround the button element with a `<div></div>` as shown on the code below but it is not working as expected. The screenshot shows how the button is being displayed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIIzy.png)

```
<?= $this->Form->button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in "></i> Sign in', [
    'templates' => [
       'button' => '<div class="col-xs-4"><button{{attrs}}>{{text}}</button></div>'],
    'type' => 'submit', 
    'class' => 'btn bg-navy btn-flat',
    'escape' => false
    ]); 
?>
```

What is the correct way to surround the button element with a `<div></div>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no `templates` options for `Form->button()` method

you have to set the template before creating the input

```
<?php
    $this->Form->setTemplates([
        'button' => '<div class="col-xs-4"><button{{attrs}}>{{text}}</button></div>'])
?>

<?= $this->Form->button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in "></i> Sign in', 
    'type' => 'submit',
    'class' => 'btn bg-navy btn-flat',
    'escape' => false
    ]); 
?>
```

remember you can also put your templates in a file so that they are used in all your forms (see the cookbook [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses))

also you can simply put the html directly in your page without using any template at all ;-)

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <?= $this->Form->button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in "></i> Sign in', 
        'type' => 'submit',
        'class' => 'btn bg-navy btn-flat',
        'escape' => false
     ]); 
    ?>
</div>
```

if you need the div element just in one single form maybe you don't need the template at all.

Comment: Saw the button element in the templates here: https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#%24_defaultConfig so thought it would work. Tried the second option and for whatever reason it wasn't working because <div class="col-xs-8"> col in the row had been used in a custom template. Solution one works fine for the bootstrap theme I am using, thanks :).